# laravel post request says page not defined

Tags: php, laravel

I want to call Laravel redirect from controller per documentation

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/redirects#redirecting-controller-actions

but I get this error:

> InvalidArgumentException Route [/gosterge_paneli] not defined.

here is how my codes look like

**layout.blade.php**

```
$("#myRedirectButton").click(function(){

            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });

            $.ajax({
                method: 'post',
                dataType: 'text',
                url: 'redirect-testing-link',
                success: function (data)
                {

                }
            });
});
```

**web.php**

```
Route::post('/redirect-testing-link', function () {

    return redirect()->route('/gosterge_paneli');

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrong! 
change your action code

> for 1

**from**

```
 return redirect()->route({{ url('/gosterge_paneli') }});
```

**to**

```
Route::post('/gosterge_paneli', function(){
   //do something
})->name('gost');

return redirect()->route('gost'); //your named route
```

> for 3

**from**

```
return redirect()->action('/gosterge_paneli');
```

**to**

```
return redirect()->action('Controller@acton'); //the corresponding controller and method for `gosterge_paneli`
```

> Redirect the URL through AJAX

Firstly return the url in response

```
return response()->json([url => route('name')]);
```

Then ajax success

```
success: function(response){
  window.location.href = response.url
}
```

Comment: Route [gosterge_paneli] not defined.(although it exists)

Comment: its not named route, `route::get('/gosterge_paneli', controller@method)->name('gosterge')` , then use it like `route('gosterge')`

Comment: I updated the question. It's still not working. I wrote the error message.

Comment: Don't use slashes in `route()`, its a named route, https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes check this

Comment: i updated my answer check how you define a named route and use it in other functions,